# Python - FOR loop not writing correct values in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, nested

Hopefully someone can help me with this as none of my research has helped me. I have a simple dictionary:

```
mydict = {
    1: {1: 'Foo'},
    2: {1: 'Bar'}
    }
```

I'm duplicating each of the key / value pairs assigning new key values:

```
nextKey = len(mydict) + 1
for currKey in range(len(mydict)):
    mydict[nextKey] = mydict[currKey + 1]
    nextKey += 1
```

Which give me a **mydict** of:

```
{
    1: {1: 'Foo'},
    2: {1: 'Bar'},
    3: {1: 'Foo'},
    4: {1: 'Bar'},
    }
```

I now want to add a new key value pair to all of the existing nested dictionaries. The keys for each should be '2' and the values for each should increase for each nested dictionary:

```
newValue = 1
for key in mydict:
    mydict[key][2] = newValue
    newValue += 1
```

I am expecting:

```
{
    1: {1: 'Foo', 2: 1},
    2: {1: 'Bar', 2: 2},
    3: {1: 'Foo', 2: 3},
    4: {1: 'Bar', 2: 4},
    }
```

But this is giving me a **mydict** of:

```
{
    1: {1: 'Foo', 2: 3},
    2: {1: 'Bar', 2: 4},
    3: {1: 'Foo', 2: 3},
    4: {1: 'Bar', 2: 4},
    }
```

I have used the visualisation tool of the IDE I'm using and after I have run the loop to duplicate the key / value pairs it appears the new keys just reference the duplicated value rather than actually containing it, perhaps this has something to do with it?

[IDE Visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX40r.png)

Can anyone please help / explain?

Comment: "the new keys just reference the duplicated value rather than actually containing it". Yep, that's the answer.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because in your first loop you are not copying the nested dictionaries but rather just adding a new reference to the same dictionaries.

To maybe give a clearer example: If you were to break out of the second loop after two loops (with your original code) your output would be:

```
{1: {1: 'Foo', 2: 1}, 
2: {1: 'Bar', 2: 2}, 
3: {1: 'Foo', 2: 1}, 
4: {1: 'Bar', 2: 2}}
```

So you can fix your first loop like this:

```
for currKey in range(len(mydict)):
    mydict[nextKey] = mydict[currKey + 1].copy()
    nextKey += 1
```

The `copy()` function creates a real copy of the dictionary so that you can then access these 4 different dictionaries in your second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right. Minimal example:

```
>>> a = {1: {"a": "A"}, 2:{"b": "B"}}
>>> a[3] = a[1]
>>> a
{1: {'a': 'A'}, 2: {'b': 'B'}, 3: {'a': 'A'}}
>>> id(a[3])                           # a[1] and a[3] are the same object
140510365203264
>>> id(a[1])
140510365203264
>>> a[1]['a'] = "changed"              # so changing one affects the "oter one"
>>> a
{1: {'a': 'changed'}, 2: set(['B', 'b']), 3: {'a': 'changed'}}
```

If you want to copy objects, there are several ways to do this:

- for lists: `new = old[:]`, using the slicing notation
- for dictionaries: `dict.copy()`
- see also the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)